# Why is my UIButton not added to the custom header view of my viewForSectionHeader

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have this following code to add a button to my custom header for section.

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
  if (tableView == menuListTableView) {
      UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 40)] autorelease];

    UIButton *headerButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [headerButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 40)];
    [headerButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Gray_Gradient.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [headerButton addTarget:nil action:@selector(toggleOpen:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [headerView addSubview:headerButton];

    return headerView;
 }
 return nil;
}
```

Why is my button not added to the custom header view?? The sub view array of the headerview seems to be nil when checked in the debugging mode.

Comment: I guess you want to return `headerView` instead of `headerButton`?

Comment: yup its header view.. since i was trying too mant things.. i forgot to edit this one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I got the answer myself!!! I looked at the button code.. and the control state was set to UIControlStateSelected. instead of UIControlStateNormal. Its so ignorant of me. Sorry guys for the bothering!!

Comment: You're also adding a nil target :)

Comment: actually in a hurry to finish with this project.. i have committed few silly mistakes.. I really need to concentrate.. thank you Carl for the reply..

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the header view itself? Check the height of the header view. Also check whether the image exists. If in doubt, change the button type to rounded rect and see whether it was added properly.

Comment: thanks for the answer.. and yes i tried doing that too.. but it was not showing in the array.. and even now it doesn't seem to populate that array.. but is now displayed on the header section at least..